# looping through multi array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I am having a hard time looping through the following array -

```
array("newProduct"=>array('rmsId' => '123456789','departmentName' => 'Britax','categoryName' => 'Car Seat','productName' => 'Test Product For Britax Car Seat','productPrice' => 33.99,'productQty' => 10),
      "newProduct"=>array('rmsId' => '987654321','departmentName' => 'Stokke','categoryName' => 'Highchairs','productName' => 'Test Product For Stokke Highchair','productPrice' => 83.99,'productQty' => 20),
      "newProduct"=>array('rmsId' => '13579','departmentName' => 'Maclaren','categoryName' => 'Buggy','productName' => 'Test Product For Maclaren Buggy','productPrice' => 183.99,'productQty' => 5)
                );
```

Can someone set me off on the right track to achieving this? My goal is to add each into a MySQL db

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You array is invalid; a key can only exist once. You should probably make numeric indexes, then loop through it with `foreach()`.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to give each array key a unique identifier. Then you can loop through them.

```
$items = array(
               "product1"=>array('rmsId' => '123456789','departmentName' => 'Britax','categoryName' => 'Car Seat','productName' => 'Test Product For Britax Car Seat','productPrice' => 33.99,'productQty' => 10),
               "product2"=>array('rmsId' => '987654321','departmentName' => 'Stokke','categoryName' => 'Highchairs','productName' => 'Test Product For Stokke Highchair','productPrice' => 83.99,'productQty' => 20),
               "product3"=>array('rmsId' => '13579','departmentName' => 'Maclaren','categoryName' => 'Buggy','productName' => 'Test Product For Maclaren Buggy','productPrice' => 183.99,'productQty' => 5)
                );

foreach($items as $product) {
   echo $product['rmsId'];
   echo $product['departmentName'];
   // ... and so on
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out this one :-

```
<?php
$var = array("0"=>array('rmsId' => '123456789','departmentName' => 'Britax','categoryName' => 'Car Seat','productName' => 'Test Product For Britax Car Seat','productPrice' => 33.99,'productQty' => 10),
      "1"=>array('rmsId' => '987654321','departmentName' => 'Stokke','categoryName' => 'Highchairs','productName' => 'Test Product For Stokke Highchair','productPrice' => 83.99,'productQty' => 20),
      "2"=>array('rmsId' => '13579','departmentName' => 'Maclaren','categoryName' => 'Buggy','productName' => 'Test Product For Maclaren Buggy','productPrice' => 183.99,'productQty' => 5)
                );
          foreach ($var as $key=>$val) {
            $id = $val['rmsId'];
            $dname = $val['departmentName'];
            $cname = $val['categoryName'];
            $pname = $val['productName'];
            $price = $val['productPrice'];
            $qnt = $val['productQty'];
         $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO TABLENAME (rmsId,departmentName,categoryName,productName,productPrice,productQty) VALUE(".$id.",".$dname.",".$cname.",".$pname.",".$price.",".$qnt.")");
           }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array(array('rmsId' => '123456789','departmentName' => 'Britax','categoryName' => 'Car Seat','productName' => 'Test Product For Britax Car Seat','productPrice' => 33.99,'productQty' => 10),
      array('rmsId' => '987654321','departmentName' => 'Stokke','categoryName' => 'Highchairs','productName' => 'Test Product For Stokke Highchair','productPrice' => 83.99,'productQty' => 20),
      array('rmsId' => '13579','departmentName' => 'Maclaren','categoryName' => 'Buggy','productName' => 'Test Product For Maclaren Buggy','productPrice' => 183.99,'productQty' => 5)
                );


foreach($array as $value){
    $query = "insert into (columnname,columnname) values (".$value['rmsId'].",'".$value['departmentName']."')";
    //fire query

}
```

assuming your array format as shown
Your array stucture is not proper,try as shown